# Is it ok to call stopSelf() from within Android Service onStartCommand() ?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

I have a service that when called, checks some state values, and depending on the state, might need to call some stuff asynchronously (locationmanager + asynctask), or just save a value and exit.

I create a service rather than an intentservice, because as i mention i need to create async tasks sometimes.

I have read up on Services and i gather that i should call stopSelf when done. But in the case where i don't need to do anything, i am done when i exit from onStartCommand.

So, will it work to just call stopSelf in the last line of onStartCommand if i am done at that point? Is there any problems with that approach?

Thankful for input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just perform `if` check in the service, why won't you perform that check before starting a service, thus refrain from consuming precious resources?

To answer your question - yes, `stopSelf()` would result in stopping the `Service`, but consider not even launching it if service won't be used.

Comment: Yes, i actually thought about that. The thing is that there's a small chance that the circumstances might have changed between the broadcastreceiver that calls the service, and when the service executes the code. Or atleast that was my thinking :)